# Writing in file in php

Tags: php

trying to write in file some information, file exist, the path is correct but it doesn't work. Do I miss something or something wrong?

```
$path = "users/'.$IDN.'/list.txt";

        $fp=fopen($path,'a+');

        fwrite($fp,"here"); // doesn't work as fwrite($fp,$IDN); 
        fclose($fp);
```

Comment: to top of php page add: ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);

Comment: the problem was not in slashes, the problem was in permissions. Thanks...

Comment: @alex_mike: glad you got it figured.

Comment: so the path was really **users/'.test.'/list.txt** i find that unlikley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening and closing path using different quotes:

`$path = "users/'.$IDN.'/list.txt";`

Should be:

`$path = "users/".$IDN."/list.txt"; //all double quotes`

or

`$path = 'users/'.$IDN.'/list.txt'; //all single quotes`

Additionally, you can use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` if you want portability across multiple OS.

Eg:`$path = 'users'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$IDN.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'list.txt';`

Comment: or `"users/$IDN/list.txt";` or ...

Comment: I think using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a cleaner way...

Comment: Now the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is somewhat pointless. Forward slashes are compatible on all platforms (ever since MS-DOS 2.0 introduced directory support).

Comment: I've yet to see any one use it in 'real life'

Comment: I know of older legacy systems where this constant has been a life-saver :), And I am talking about a trading platform server which has been around for a long time... actually having DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR not only ports across different OS, but also makes code backward compatible  :)